# One day, he will get my revenge from you

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine a father who is dying under the torture of a malicious man who is killing the father for some reasons (money issues, etc.) The father at his last moments says:

> - **One day** my son will grow up and get my revenge from you.

Does the sentence above sound natural to you? I doubt if the bold part which is a direct translation from my mother language is said in English in the way I translated. Because "growing up" is a process and won't happen in a day.

Comment: "One day my son will ..." is perfectly idiomatic, though rather than "grow up" he might be "grown up".

Comment: Does it sound *natural*? No. The language of blood vengeance in English is bound to sound wooden, not natural, either quaint or foreign, or both. A native English speaker today would not expect the words "he will avenge my blood" to come from the mouth of one of his or her contemporaries. Blood vengeance is a practice of a pre-industrialized world, of societies which are, in the words of anthropologists, "honor-shame cultures", and Western English-speaking industrialized democracies are no longer such. A translation must cross not only a linguistic divide but a cultural one.

Comment: @TRomano do you mean I have to say: "One day my son will be grown up"? Does it sound more idiomatic than "...will grow up" to you? If yes, then is it as common as "have revenge" or "take revenge"?

Comment: No, "will be grown up" is normal English and it is vastly more common than  the formulaic language of the honor code of blood vengeance, which is not part of the *natural* vocabulary of the contemporary native speaker of English.  No native English speaker who borrows money from shady characters willing to kill any lendee who fails to pay up (your example) would say "My son will take his vengeance" or "avenge my blood". He might say "My son will *get even with you* for this", assuming the family adheres to such an honor code, which is not likely.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you take revenge **on** someone, or **for** something - you don't take it *from* them. There are multiple ways of expressing this:

> - to take revenge (against somebody)
> - to seek revenge (against someone)
> - get revenge against someone
> - take revenge (on someone) (for something)

However, in the example you have provided:

> One day my son will grow up and get my revenge from you.

...implies that the son is taking the father's revenge, which is not possible. Revenge is a personal thing - you can take it for yourself, or you can take it on behalf of somebody else, but you can't take somebody else's revenge. The closest alternatives to your sentence would probably be along the lines of:

> - One day my son will grow up and *take/seek/get* his revenge (from you).
> - One day my sone will grow up and revenge me. *(correct, but not commonly used)*

Another alternative available is the word **avenge**, which (in my opinion) is more suited to this scenario.

*avenge* and *revenge* both mean to seek or get vengeance. However, avenge specifically means to take vengeance or exact satisfaction for (a wrong) by punishing the wrongdoer, which is exactly what you describe.

> - One day my son will grow up and avenge me.
> - One day my son will grow up and avenge my death.

...are two ways of expressing this, but it can be reworded in a number of fashions.

Comment: @A-friend - I've updated my comment to (hopefully) include this.

Comment: Mike, what about if dad said: "One day my son will grow up and avenge my (blood)"? does it make sense to you? [This is another way we say it in our language.]

Comment: Meanwhile, is it possible to say: "One day my son will grow up and avenge me (from you)"?

Comment: And my last question. To make sure I got you well, please answer this question of mine too. Imagine in a football match, one team overcomes the other and defeats it e.g. 3-0. The losing team's coach says: "I will take revenge on them for this loss" where the verb "avenge" cannot be used, because it concerns some other issues where someone is seeking justice and not personal issues with someone else. Do you confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two phrases that you will often hear in movies:

> "One day, [someone] will **avenge** me!" (or simply the command **"Avenge me!"**)
>
> "(One day) I will **have my revenge**!"

To have *revenge* is to ***get*** vengeance for some wrongdoing done to yourself. To *avenge* is to ***take*** vengeance for some wrongdoing done primarily to someone else.  Thus the name of the superhero team *The Avengers*, as illustrated by this quote from the 2012 movie of the same name:

> ["Because if we can't protect the Earth, you can be damned well sure we'll avenge it."](https://youtu.be/W3GF1x0-VX0?t=112)

In your example, either works (with the proper phrasing), but as mike suggests, *avenge* probably works better.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Andrew, but do the sentences: "One day I will have / get / seek my revenge" and "One day I will revenge" mean the same? If yes, which one is more common in modern AmE these days? It seems that the word "revenge" is mostly used as a noun in English by googling the examples of this word.

Comment: Although the dictionary disagrees, "revenge" isn't really used much as a verb.  It's almost exclusively used as a noun -- either **get** revenge or **have** revenge (or sometimes **seek**, but this is a much weaker statement since it just means *go looking* while the others imply you will *find* revenge).  If you use revenge as a verb, people might think you meant to say "avenge" and be confused (because you can't really *avenge* yourself).

Comment: you sais: "", but on Cambridge English Dictionary you will easily find such example: "She determined to avenge (herself) on the killer." How would you explain this?

Comment: Again, this is more about how the words are *most commonly* used, and not just what the dictionary says they *mean*.  If someone wrongs you by harming you, personally, the most common expression is to "take revenge" for the wrong.  If someone wrongs you by harming someone or something you care about, the most common expression is "to avenge" that person.

Comment: The dictionary says, for example, "they avenged themselves on the interlopers" implying that each of the group was avenging the *others* in the group, sort of a collective "avenging".  The Marvel Avengers are personally wronged by the harm their enemies do to everyone on Earth, so they can *avenge* that wrong.

Comment: I guess the difference is that *revenge* is about getting a kind of *individual* justice, while *avenge* is more about getting generic *Justice* by punishing those who do wrong.  You can *avenge* some wrong that didn't actually affect you *personally*, while *revenge* is always personal.